# Url against jQuery ui autocomplete selected value

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

```
    $( function() {
        function log( message ) {
            $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
            $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
        }
        $( "#searchcomplete" ).autocomplete({
            source: "<?php echo base_url('home/search');?>",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );

            }
        });
    } );
```

I don't know how to set a url against the user's selected id in this widget. What i want here is when user select any option from dropdown and click on it then page will be redirected to url against that selected id.

Comment: Have you tried using `window.location.href = <my url>`? How exactly is the URL constructed?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using form.

```
<form id="tpsearch" action="" method="post">
     <input type="text" id="searchcomplete">
     <button type="submit" class="icon-search"></button>
</form>
```

and select function will be from autocomplete:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
          log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
          $("#tpsearch").attr("action", "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/controller/action/" + ui.item.id);
        }
```